# Flex4: Fade in/out items in list when filtering

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, fadeout

In Flex 4 I have a list where every product in it is rendered through an ItemRenderer. Now, when I filter the list I want to fadeout the products that are removed. I can't add the fadeout effect to the hideEffect of the item renderer since renderers are being reused. Anyone a valid (easy) solution on how the fadeout the products correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In Flex 3, you used an itemChange effect.  Flex 4 doesn't have that, though.

Does this [question help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917566/whats-the-itemchangeeffect-equivalent-in-spark-list)?

My first impulse is to bake the effects into the itemRenderer, you just have to start the fade out effect in the dataChange event; when it is complete, change the data and do a fade in effect.